# HTML Audio Play/Stop

Tags: audio, playback

I'm making a chat application and one of the features is sending a sound. The HTML that gets sent is the following:

```
<p>
   <audio autoplay>
      <source src="sounds/lol.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
   LOL
   <a href="#" id="soundStop">Stop</a>
   <a href="#" id="soundPlay" style="display:none;">Play</a>
</p>
```

The 'autoplay' works fine when it is sent the first time. So now i need a play/stop link to hear the sound again as many times as you want. I have the following Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '#soundStop', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next("a").show();
    $('audio').each(function(){
        this.pause();
        this.currentTime = 0;
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click', '#soundPlay', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev("a").show();
    $(this).closest("audio").play();
    //alert("play sound again!");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The stop function works (although I'm not sure targeting all 'audio' elements is a good idea). But I'm stuck at how to target the audio element to .play() in the second function. I might be going at this the completely wrong way?

Any help or advice is appreciated.

EDIT: Just to clarify, there might be multiple instances of these sounds that get sent which is why I need a way to only target that specific 'audio' for each.

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you use the Ready to Use Controls of audio tag. It'll serve your purpose.

**Try this code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <audio autoplay controls>
       <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   </audio>

</body>
</html>
```

**Customer Controls**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <audio id="player" src="horse.ogg"></audio>
<div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">Volume Up</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1">Volume Down</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got a code for Custom Play Button

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <a onclick="this.firstChild.play()">
<audio autoplay src="horse.ogg"></audio>Play</a>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't really fit into the code I provided. Just need the way to target the specific audio element in the jQuery function i provided.